# Logic of hangman game with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a hangman game and I need help with the logic. I am in a beginners class so I want to try and build this using beginners syntax. What I am trying to figure out

2) My issue is I need to display dashes (-) that represent blank lines and they need to be the same length of the randomly chosen word. In addition, every time a letter is correctly guessed, I need to replace the dashes with the correctly chosen letter. A solution I have thought of is making an empty array and then assigning it the dash signs in a for loop that is the length of the string and then replacing the indexes of specific dashes with matched letters, but I am not sure if this will work.

```
var randomWords = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
var numWins = 0;
var chosenWord = randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomWords.length)];
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    // var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    var dashes = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < chosenWord.length; x++) {
      dashes += " - ";
      // document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = blankLines;
      // document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = ;
    }
    document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = dashes;
```

Trying to replace a dash with a letter in lines below. But both commented out code and non commented out codes work. That is why I am thinking of using an empty array but not sure if I can fill it with data using a foor loop

```
     // for (x = 0; x < chosenWord.length; x++)
     // {
     //         dashes[x] = "a";
     //         dahes.charAt(x) = 'a';
     // }
     dashes.charAt(0) = "a";
     document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = dashes;
```

Comment: If you're not sure if it will work, you should try it and find out ;) Your idea of replacing strings in an array is a good one and I'd suggest you go that way. Read up on [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). It will help you a lot when you want to display what's in the array.

Comment: It appears you haven't actually asked a question. Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service. Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This one should work. In the first case (if there's a white space in the word) it will display a whitespace. In the second case, it will replace every letter of the word with a dash.

```js
var dashes = "";


for (i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
  if (chosenWord.charAt(i) == " ") {
    dashes += " ";
  } else {
    dashes += "-";
  }
}
```

Comment: I've done this game few months ago, I could send you the code, if you wish.

Comment: Okay sure. But I wont look at it until I am just completely stumped and nothing I have done works.